# Video won't play after pausing in chrome html

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Tested my code in IE and it works fine. This is the code i have for my video:

```
    <video width="640" height="360" controls preload="none">
        <source src="../media/videoplayback.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
```

The video loads properly and starts properly, but when i pause the video and try to play it again or when i try to skip to a specific time sequence in the video, the video crashes. The source is correct, i have tried moving the video to different folders as well. I get "a network error caused the video to fail part-way" when using a player. I tried removing the player and still didn't work.

Comment: Needless to say that that shouldn't happen. Have you tried removing `preload="none"`?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. After pausing the video, I wasn't able to play it again. Cause behind this seems to be, that the inbuild webserver of my development environment (WebStorm), does not support the partial comment, which chrome uses while seeking thru the video.

I've opened the page locally (file://test/bla.html instead of http://localhost:1234/bla.html) and it worked right away. So in order to make it work, you need a webserver capable of the partial command.

Best Regards
Christian